# How to capture n groups in regex so i can substitute them in js

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have following string:

> [{par1}, {par2}, ..., {parN}]

And I am capturing this with following regex:

```
(\{\S*\})
```

This works fine, and captures in groups my params: $1 = par1, $2 = par2... etc

My question is, I want to do some operation in javascript with all those groups.
I know how to do it for 1 group.

```
str.replace(new RegExp((\{\S*\}),g),'whatever'+$1) //Probably need to add more escape characters
```

My question is how to replace $1 to 'whatever+'$1, $2 to 'whatever'+$2... etc

i.e

> [{par1},{par2}] ==> [mypar1,mypar2]

**EDIT**

To explain what i want to do more detailed with parameters:

From [{par1},{par2}] I need to extract par1 and par2, so i can call a function with them, which will return different values:

```
function translate(par) {
  //return different things for every parameter
}
//so finally will be like: 
str.replace(new RegExp((\{\S*\}),g),translate($1))
```

Comment: In the end, do you just want to remove all braces? `.replace(/[{}]+/g, '')`?

Comment: no no, i want to remove braces, get the parameter itself, and do operation with that parameter. so it wont really be always the same thing to replace, it will be dependant on the parameter

Comment: If you need to check these values in some more code, you need to use the anonymous method used as a second argument to `replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback function as a second argument of `String.replace` function:

```
var str = '[{par1}, {par2}, ..., {parN}]',
    prefix = 'whatever',
    replaced = str.replace(/\{(\S+)\}/g, function (p0, p1) {
        // ... some other logic
        return prefix + p1;
    });

console.log(replaced);  // "[whateverpar1, whateverpar2, ..., whateverparN]"
```

Comment: Perfect! Did not know replace accepted a function as callback for all the args! Thank you very much!